# Why do Klingons in ENT look different than in TOS?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, star-trek-enterprise

Why do the Klingons in ENT look different than the Klingons in TOS?

I understand the explanation for the difference after TOS, but since ENT is before TOS.

Comment: Watch episodes 15 and 16 of Enterprise season 4.

Answer (score 2):

I think the way they explained it was that TOS klingons were augments and we never actually saw a normal klingon in TOS (until the movies anyway)